# Same Type Constraint in Multiple Protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I have to set a constraint for one type to multiple protocol:

```
public protocol Test: Hashable { }

public protocol Foo {
    func function() -> Test
}

public protocol Bar {
    func function(argument: Test) -> Test
}
```

I want to use these protocols in one class:

```
public class Baz<T: Test> {
    var FooImpl: Foo
    var BarImpl: Bar
}
```

and after I could do this :

```
class TestImpl : Test { }

let baz = Baz()
baz.BarImpl.function(TestImpl())
```

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT : concretely I try to implement a genetic algorithm with Generator, Merger, Mutator, and FitnessEvaluator separated so I have:

```
public protocol Genotype : Hashable {
}

public protocol CandidateGenerator{
    func generateRandomly<T: Genotype>() -> T
}

public protocol CandidateMerger {
    func merge<T: Genotype>(first: T, second: T) -> T
}

public protocol CandidateMutator {
    func mutate<T: Genotype>(candidate: T) -> T
}

public protocol FitnessEvaluator {
    func evaluate<T: Genotype>(genotype: T) -> Double
}

public class GeneticAlgorithm<T: Genotype> {
    private let generator: CandidateGenerator
    private let merger: CandidateMerger
    private let mutator: CandidateMutator
    private let evaluator: FitnessEvaluator
// ...
}

// at use 
class Test : Genotype { ... }

class Generator : CandidateGenerator {
    func generateRandomly<T: Genotype>() -> T {
        let a = Test()
        return a // <- Error here : cannot convert return expression of type 'Test' to return type 'T'
    }
}
```

EDIT :

I tried to use the associedtype but I can't constrain it to Genotype, so my protocols could accept various types not implementing my protocol :

```
protocol CandidateGenerator {
    associatedtype Genottype

    func generateRandomly() -> Genottype
}

class CandidateGenImpl : CandidateGenerator {
    typealias Genottype = Test

    func generateRandomly() -> Test {
        return /* random */ Test()
    }
}

class Other { } // not implement Genotype

class CandidateGenImpl2 : CandidateGenerator {
    typealias Genottype = Other

    func generateRandomly() -> Other {
        return /* random */ Other()
    }
}
```

I tried to do this :

```
associatedType Genottype = Genotype
```

but it doesn't work...

hope this helps to understand

Comment: TheType could be a generic type like another protocol..

Comment: Could you please tell us what you want your `generateRandomly` method to do? The caller of a generic function dictates what the generic placeholder type will be, not the callee – therefore you cannot just return a new `Test` instance. If you want the caller to decide the return type of the function, then you need to add an initialiser requirement to the `Genotype` protocol, so that you can construct an instance of any type that conforms to it. If you want to be able to return 'any type that conforms to Genotype', then you want a [type-erasure](http://robnapier.net/erasure).

Comment: As the method name said, the generatorRandomly method generate randomly a instance of a class which implement Genotype. In my example I want it to do a class called Test, but I could use all my logic of genetic in an other project with another class MouseADN. - You said that I need a initialiser, so I change my protocol to be directly a subclass of NSObject, so It already has a init(). I still have the error, even if let a: Genotype = Test() and the error "cannot convert return expression of type 'Genotype' to return type 'T'" whereas I define T conforms to Genotype.... "T: Genotype"

Comment: Randomly creating and returning an instance of a type that conforms to `Genotype` requires the return type to be 'any type that conforms to `Genotype`' – therefore as `Genotype` has `associatedtype` requirements, you'll need a type-erasure. If you [edit] all this information into the question itself, I'd be happy to write an answer.